# Avoiding thread suspend or kill

Tags: windows, multithreading, security, process

I need to avoid suspending of my thread. Is this possible. Or Is it possible to avoid kill of thread or process.
I need to implement;

CreateProcess(...)
BeginThread(...)

And this process or thread must;
- can't be killed
- can't be suspended

Is this possible under windows.

For example when i try to kill the system idle process, windows doesnt allow me to kill. Can we do same for our own created processes.

Comment: No, that's not possible. Those are system processes that are afforded special protection. You're not creating a system process.

Comment: That darned "Idle" process, it is always using 98% CPU on my machine!

Comment: @HansPassant - obviously you are not working hard enough.  I will send you some of my bugs & then, perhaps, we can get more use out of your box...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this were possible, viri and trojans would be doing it.  If it becomes possible, the next version of Windows, or 'Critical security update', will block off the wormhole, (again).

The system 'idle process' probably just halts the CPU/s in a loop.  It may not even exist as a real process.